# Django not rendering css style on text stored in database

Tags: django-templates

I format text with javascript and after that I store it in database, but when I get this text from database and display in a template then django do not apply css format tags, and just display them as text instead of apply. Please tell what is the problem?

Comment: more information is needed. what does the text look like when it comes out of the database? What does it look like when the browser recieves it? What do your templates look like?

Comment: when i print text in template then both text and css styles displayed as text and not css applied on text . e.g; <h1> this is heading </h1>

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to use the `safe`-filter in your template
see the django docu [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe)!